# Groovy slash operator (Jenkins job-dsl)

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

We would like to understand a couple of legacy job-dsl scripts but don't know what "slash operator" means in this context (as it cant be division):

```
def command = (shells.first() / command)
```

We have tried to look it up in several Groovy books but only found the trivial solution that it means 'division'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an XML [Node](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html) operation, to return a sub-node of a XML node, or create it if it doesn't exist. Probably the `command` node under the first of your `shells` nodes here.

Groovy allows [operator overloading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading), so it *is* the same "division" operator, just redefined somewhat. This is common (but also controversial) in other languages allowing operator overloading, but does allow for richer DSLs.

Having had a quick look at (an old copy of) the [JobDSL source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin), it seems that they're doing it using a class `NodeEnhancement`, notably this JavaDoc:

```
/**
Add div and leftShift operators to Node.
div - Will return the first child that matches name, and if it doesn't exists, it creates
...
**/
```

Comment: That's correct. Also have a look at the Job DSL wiki which explains the overloaded operators for XML manipulation: https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block#transforming-xml

Comment: This took some effort to track down